# GTK: Destroy window and run an external script on button clicked

Tags: gtk, pygtk, signals

That's pretty much the question's title. I must be missing some signals interpretation here...

On PyGTK, I'm doing:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.gladefile = gladefile
        self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile, 'some_window')
        self.window = self.wTree.get_widget('some_window')
        events = { 'on_code_submit_clicked' : self.submit }
        self.wTree.signal_autoconnect(events)

    def submit(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        os.system('external_script')
        code = Foo()
```

What's happening, is that when the button is clicked, it stay pressed, then the script runs, and after the external program is closed, the window "blinks", getting destroyed and recreated again.

I also tried the "pressed" and "released" signals.

The behavior I need:

1. Click on the button
2. Destroy the current window
3. Run external script (that will open another program's window)
4. Recreate the Foo() window after closing the external app.

What I can imagine is that the event is being run *during* the *clicked* event, not after. That's why the window remain opened. The PyGTK docs don't say anything about something like [`gtk_signal_connect_after`](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Graphics/by-node/gtk+-1.1.1/gtk_4.html) on the [glade page](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gladexml.html), that leaves me totally lost about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hide the window and show it after the external script?

```
self.window.hide()
os.system('external_script')
self.window.show()
```

Comment: Because that gives me the same behavior. Sorry I didn't write that I also tried that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to call the external script from a thread.

I haven't worked with threads with python, but it looks like the [threading module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) would do the job (at least that's what I would try). Glib also has thread support, but I can't find the pygtk docs for it.

When the external script has finished, don't recreate `Foo` from the thread but schedule a callback function to do so using [`gobject.idle_add`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add). This is because all GUI work should be done on the gtk event thread, otherwise your program may crash.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution... it's easy as.

```
    self.window.hide()
    glib.idle_add(subprocess.call, ['external_script', 'param'])
    glib.idle_add(self.window.show)
```